# Should links contains the authentication token in HateOAS?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I'm using Spring MVC and Spring HateOAS to make a restful and stateless JSON API.

Everything works fine. But i have a "conception" question. My API use an authentication token in every request. For example, you use the login API to get your authentication token, and when you call my API you must use it like this :

```
http://some_host/api/foo/bar?token=abcd
```

The API always respond a JSON and links are generated via Spring HateOAS. For exemple :

```
{
    "label" : "foo",
    "links" : [
        "rel" : "self",
        "href" : "http://some_host/api/foo/bar/1234656"
    ]
}
```

The question is : Should i add the authentication token in the generated URL ? (so it will be `http://some_host/api/foo/bar/1234656?token=abcd`)

I can't find any advice or convention for that.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, authentication tokens are communicated via standard HTTP headers (such as the Authorization header in the case of HTTP Basic or Digest). The other common one is via a cookie. In Servlet environments, this is usually the JSESSIONID cookie.

Generally speaking, you shouldn't see authentication tokens passed as part of the request URL.

Comment: Actually, the API can handle the authentication token in several ways. We can handle the token in a custom HTTP token, we handle the HTTP basic authentication and we handle the token in the query string.

Comment: I know that it *can* handle tokens in the query string, but it probably shouldn't. My point is that you're probably not seeing a whole lot of advice on the subject because few people are doing it that way (they are instead using headers).

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the answer is definitely no.

`http://some_host/api/foo/bar/1234656` is supposed to be the **uniform** identifier (URI) and location (URL) for that resource. It's the one URL you can rely on. You can always get the resource using that URL but you'll never get the resource with `http://some_host/api/foo/bar?token=abcd` again, because the token will expire.

Calling the URL with the token appended is one thing, but it should never appear in the link, because it has nothing to do with the resource. It's the client's responsibility to send the token, not the server's one.